# Parsing .txt file line by line

Tags: java, file, parsing, file-io

i am trying to parse a .txt file. I need to look at the file line by line and get access to information enclosed by ''. Here what i have tried so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] test;
    String word;
    Scanner inputStream = null;
    try
    {
        inputStream = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("stuff.txt"));
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        System.out.println("output.txt was not found, or could not be opened");
    }
    while(inputStream.hasNextLine())
    {
        word = inputStream.nextLine();
        test = word.split("['']");
        for(int i = 0; i < test.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(test[i]);
        }
    }

}
```

and here is the format of my input file:

```
type = 'Home'
title = 'please work'
start = '2000, september, 10, 10, 10'
end = '2010, october, 20, 20, 20'
comment = 'please word '
```

I need to get access to type, title, comment, and the individual values in start and end

Comment: Please extend the title of your question with more depth.

Comment: Why you don't try to use a regexp? Something like "\(.+\) = '.+'"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That file looks like a property file, then you can consider to use that format of file.

Also, you should splut using '=' instead brackets.